# Php, Mysql - How to working with big data in my case

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table with big data, Example in **http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee61b/3**

**Table 1** like

```
CREATE TABLE `t1`(
  `id` int(4) ,
  `name` varchar(40),
  `signal` int(4)
)
;

INSERT INTO `t1`
(`id`, `name`, `signal`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 1),
    (2, 'b', 1),
    (3, 'c', 0),
    (4, 'd', 0)
;
```

And **table 2** like

```
CREATE TABLE `t2`(
  `uid` int(4),
  `type` int(4),
  `usignal` int(4)
)
;

INSERT INTO `t2`
(`uid`, `type`, `usignal`)
VALUES
    (3, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (4, 1, 0),
    (2, 2, 0)
;
```

Now i try to get all record have conditional like

1. All record in table 1 has `signal` = 1

2. OR(+) all record in table 1 has `id` in (SELECT uid FROM  `t2` WHERE t2.type = 1 AND t2.usignal = 1)

I do that like

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` AS g1
WHERE g1.signal = 1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM  `t1` AS g1
WHERE g1.id
IN (
    SELECT uid
    FROM  `t2` AS g2
    WHERE g2.usignal = 1 AND g2.type = 1
)
```

But I must do some conditional on that (mybe join,...) and i do that like

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` AS g1
WHERE g1.signal = 1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM  `t1` AS g1
WHERE g1.id
IN (
    SELECT uid
    FROM  `t2` AS g2
    WHERE g2.usignal = 1 AND g2.type = 1
)

/*dynamic other join query here */
and id>=1 /*dynamic conditional query here*/
order by id desc limit 0,20
```

That working well if data is small, But my data is bigger and that fail while execute

How can i do that thanks

**Edit:


What about my sql? Is that make execute slowly and make it timeout?**

**Edit02:**

I using phpmyadmin and click index to `t1(id, signal)` and `t2(type, unsignal)` 

And i add id primary key fo both table example in
**http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d88a9/1**

But in real my tables have about 10 column. And i using left join but that's still timeout :(

Comment: do You have indexes ?

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider creating an index on each table

Comment: Are the queries exactly the same as you sent? If not there may be need for some more indices. You can add `EXPLAIN` keyword to the start of your query in order to see the possible index uses (and not usages).

Answer (score 1):

Try to get rid of your sub query and use join , i have also removed the union from the query and for this i have enclosed the conditions in braces to meet your union needs

```
SELECT g1.* FROM `t1` AS g1
left join `t2` AS g2 on (g1.id=g2.uid)
WHERE (
(g2.usignal = 1 AND g2.type = 1 )
 OR g1.signal = 1      
  )
order by id desc limit 0,20
```

Also make sure you have proper index on your columns

[**See this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee61b/17)

Comment: @freestyle Try these indexes if id of t1 is not primary key then make it first primary  add index on your join column that is uid then look for the involve in the `WHERE` clause and index them also 


`ALTER TABLE t2 ADD INDEX test_index (uid);
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get so that we can answer your question .. you can set the maximum execution time from php ini like this :`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` And your task will work for 300 seconds instead of 30 .

Answer (score 0):

Index `t1` on `signal`, and `t2` on (`usignal`,`utype`).

Define your primary keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indices? Make sure that you created the proper ones.

For `t1` it seems that you need an index on (`id`, `signal`) tuple.
For `t2` you need an index on (`usignal`, `type`) tuple.

This is how you can add them if you already don't have (according to the create tables you don't):

```
create index 'id_signal_index' on t1 (`id`, `signal`);
create index 'id_usignal_index' on t2 (`usignal`, `type`);
```

It is usually a good practice to have primary key for `id` with auto increment in a table like `t1`.

Also convert the inner query into left join query, which is explained in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried joining instead of that nested select (which won't be fast)?

```
SELECT g1.* FROM `t1` AS g1
LEFT JOIN `t2` AS g2 ON g2.uid = g1.id 
WHERE g1.signal = 1
 OR (g2.usignal = 1 AND g2.type = 1)

/*dynamic other join query here */

and id>=1 /*dynamic conditional query here*/
order by id desc limit 0,20
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL-Fiddle  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee61b/3  there is an option down below in the green navigation bar: "+ view execution plan".  You can also get to this information by adding "EXPLAIN" to the front of your query.

In you case the result looks something like this:

```
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | g1          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
|    2 | UNION        | g1          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    4 |             |
|    2 | UNION        | <subquery3> | eq_ref | distinct_key  | distinct_key | 4       | func |    1 |             |
|    3 | MATERIALIZED | g2          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2>  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL | NULL |             |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Look at the column "possible_keys": you have NULL everywhere. That is bad, it means that the database has to search sequentially through your data to find something.

If you add the right primary keys and indexes to your database, then every search will be done using a clever data structure like a tree, and will be much faster, especially for large date:

```
+------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type  | table      | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | g1         | ref    | signal          | signal  | 5       | const       |    2 |             |
|    2 | UNION        | g2         | ref    | PRIMARY,usignal | usignal | 5       | const       |    2 | Using where |
|    2 | UNION        | g1         | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 4       | test.g2.uid |    1 |             |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL    | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL        | NULL |             |
+------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

So: read up on Primary Keys and Indexes and apply this knowledge to your example.